# QGIS 3 wrong conversion from QGIS layer to KML or GeoJSON file

Tags: qgis, geojson, kml

I want to save my work as the .kml file

Unfortunately, I've encountered a serious problem. Once loaded in Google Earth I have something like below or nothing.

A similar thing occurs with the geoJSON file. Does anyone know where the problem might be? I've never seen it before

Both the project and work are in EPSG:4376 WGS84 coordinate system

[image]

Comment: Please check, which CRS the "to-be-exported" layer actually has.

Comment: Neither KML or GeoJSON can be saved in EPSG:4376.  The CRS of KML is http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/0/LonLat84 and for GeoJSON it is http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/0/CRS84

Answer (score 1):

OK. The problem is sorted.

Next time we should:

1. Open the new blank project in QGIS
2. Set the proper project CRS
3. Load XYZ map tile (optionally)
4. Load our SQLITE layer (instead of selection from main bar, just drag from your directory and drop into your QGIS file)
5. Export as KML